# Function to fill cell using ROW() COLUMN() with "+-X"

Tags: excel

I have two columns with values.
A cell in the first column has the same value as the cell one row
above and one column to the right (except for the uppermost cell of course).

I want that a cell in the first column fills automatically
once I put a value into the row above on column to the right.

[image: excel table]

How do I do that?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Post few sample data then show your desired output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty basic Excel functionality:

This can be handled, using a simple formula:
In cell A3, you put the formula `=B2`,
In cell A4, you put the formula `=B3`, ...

In order to do this for a whole bunch of cells, you put your cursor on the right bottom corner of the cell you want to "copy", you click left, keep the left mouse-key and drag and drop down.

(You can use an `If(IfBlank(), ...)` construction for getting nicer results (for avoiding the zero).

After a while you can have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought something like ==ROW()-1, Column()+1 would work

Comment: @VeraMaria: when reading your question I already thought you were making things too complicated :-) If my answer solves your question, please upvote and/or accept it (this is the way this site works).